# Unable to find the text at node

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Unable to find text at node in enzyme

I have a Wallet component and it is connected to redux store and I am running a test in Wallet.test.js and i want to check that the walllet component contains the text 'Wallet balace: 20' at h3 tag but i am getting error **Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.**

Wallet.js --->

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Wallet extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3 className='balance' >Wallet balance: {this.props.balance}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      balance: state.balance
   }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Wallet)
```

---

Walltet.test.js---->

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import Wallet  from './Wallet'

import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


describe('Wallet',()=>{
    const props = {balance:20}
    const wallet = shallow(<Wallet {...props} />)

    it('renders properly', ()=>{
       expect(wallet).toMatchSnapshot()  
    })

    it('display the balance from props',()=>{
        expect(wallet.find('.balance').text()).toEqual('Wallet balance: 20')
    })
})
```

test result:-

***● Wallet › display the balance from props***

***Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.***

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting the connected HOC and shallow render is rendering only the first layer so it will be `Wallet` with its props, you can solve this with 2 ways:
1. export also the Wallet component and shallow render it also

```
export class Wallet extends React.Component {
```

and in test

```
import Wallet, { Wallet as WalletComponent }  from './Wallet'
```

or use a `mount` method that will perform a deep render:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
```

Comment: third options: using `.dive()` https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1002#issuecomment-310796612

Comment: Thanks for help :)